# Nikon 50mm f/1.8 D has less distortion than Nikon 50mm f/1.8 G?

Tags: lens, nikon, distortion

Some of the [Amazon reviews](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Y1AYAC) say that Nikon 50mm f/1.8 D has less distortion than Nikon 50mm f/1.8 G?

> The D is about $80 cheaper, is smaller, lighter, has less distortion, and has manual aperture control.

D is an older version, and G has got more blades, so on what basis is do they say that distortion is lesser on the older lens?

Is this factor a deal breaker? Why would anyone purchase G then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most lenses have some amount of distortion, it just may not be measurable or significant.

[Thom Hogan](http://bythom.com/Nikkor50AF-Slensreview.htm) says of the f/1.4G:

> Linear distortion is low (though slightly higher than the f/1.4G) and
>   barrel in nature. At under 0.5% it's not something I'd bother
>   correcting unless I had software that did automatic correction based
>   on EXIF data, in which case I'd just let that do its thing.

[slrgear](http://www.slrgear.com/reviews/showproduct.php/product/97/cat/12) say this about the 50mm f/1.8

> Distortion  The 50mm ƒ/1.8 shows no distortion when mounted on the
>   sub-frame D200. On the full-frame D3x, there is a negligible (+0.1%)
>   amount of barrel distortion apparent in the corners.

Both lenses have 7 aperture blades, but that doesn't affect distortion.  The f/1.8G blades are rounded, which will make the bokeh a bit more circular.

The more expensive f/1.8G has the following advantages over the f/1.8D

- sharper in the centre at wide apertures
- much sharper in the corners at wide apertures, most apparent with FX bodies
- AF-S focusing motor

Disadvantages

- more expensive
- lack of an aperture ring
- bigger and heavier
- 58mm filter thread (unusual for a Nikon lens - f/1.8D uses more common 52mm filters

So in summary, I don't think the distortion is a deal breaker.  You would buy the f/1.8G if you needed an AF-S motor built in, or if sharpness was a big issue.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest reason to buy the G version: it has an AF-S motor. If you're using a camera that doesn't drive the older screwdriver lenses, then the D version won't autofocus. That is, in the current body line-up the 3100 and 5100 can not focus the D version, while the higher end models can.

How much distortion is enough to be considered a deal breaker? How much distortion needs to be evident for you to notice it for everyday, real-world use? If you are shooting architecture (full of straight lines) then distortion is more important, and you should be looking at PC lenses; if you're shooting, well, just about anything else, you'll probably never notice it. Plus, distortion is so easily correctable in Lightroom that I never give it much thought.

[Some distortion numbers to chew on](http://www.lenstip.com/308.6-Lens_review-Nikon_Nikkor_AF-S_50_mm_f_1.8G_Distortion.html).

Comment: if you have that lens can you post here a picture showing maximum distortion?

Comment: also, thanks for your link. I saw `-0.82` on 1.4G? That means the distortion is worse on 1.4G as compared to 1.8G?

Comment: I have a pre-D 50 1.8 -- old! Yes, the 1.4G has even more distortion.

Comment: Dan, thanks. Difficult to believe. :) Didn't hear that in 1.4G's reviews on dpreview.

Comment: dpreview mentions it in their Studio Tests, noting that it's basically unnoticeable on DX and minimally noticeable on FX when shooting real-world subjects.