# What is the difference between the Nikon 50mm f/1.8D and Nikon 50mm f/1.8G on a D7000?

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d7000, prime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between using a 50mm f/1.8G and a 50mm f/1.8D with a Nikon D80?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/whats-the-difference-between-using-a-50mm-f-1-8g-and-a-50mm-f-1-8d-with-a-nikon)

I recently got a D7000 and using a [28-200mm f/3.5-5.6 AF-D](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/28200af.htm). Now I'm looking to into getting a 50mm prime lens for portrait shots.

Doing some research, I noticed there are two types of f/1.8 lens, the D and G, with a significant price difference (almost double).
What are the main difference between the two and which would you recommend?

Comment: Is this fundamentally the same as [What's the difference between using a 50mm f/1.8G and a 50mm f/1.8D with a Nikon D80?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/whats-the-difference-between-using-a-50mm-f-1-8g-and-a-50mm-f-1-8d-with-a-nikon), just with a newer camera body in basically the same line?

Comment: Also see the specific--issue question n [Nikon 50mm f/1.8 D has less distortion than Nikon 50mm f/1.8 G?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20378/nikon-50mm-f-1-8-d-has-less-distortion-than-nikon-50mm-f-1-8-g)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The G lens, being an AF-S lens, will focus a bit more quietly.  It will autofocus on bodies without an AF motor, which is of no benefit to a D7000 owner.

Both are sharp.  The G lens is a bit sharper wide open.  It's bigger, less plasticy and looks nicer than the D.  I think you'll be hard pressed to tell the difference in sharpness between the two in general use.

The G lens has rounded blades, so might give better bokeh, but this is subjective.

It also has a manual focus override, so you can manually focus without switching the lens to M.

I should mention that the "G" designation means that the lens does not have an aperture ring, which prevents it from working well with a film camera.  Not needed with the D7000.

I've upgraded from the 1.8D to the 1.4G myself.  Would have been happy with the 1.8G but found a good second-hand 1.4G.  Obviously I thought it worth upgrading, but the differences are incremental and subjective.  I think the manual focus override and slight improvement in sharpness and bokeh worth it for me, but it's really an personal choice.  If you can visit a shop and try them on your body, you may want to buy the G lens just on looks and ergonomics alone.